# How can I display dynamic key of array in the laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My controller like this :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $param = $request->all();
    $data = $this->itemDetailRepository->getData($param);
    return view('item-detail.index', compact('param'))
        ->withItems(count($data)>0?$data:null);
}
```

If I debug `$data` or in laravel (`dd($data)`), the result like this :

[image]

So the array `$data` is collection and pagination like that

If I click in the attributes section, it display like this :

```
#attributes: array:5 [▼
  "item_number" => "AB-0001"
  "total_quantity" => "1000"
  "location-a" => "500"
  "location-b" => "500"
]
```

So the array data is there

In the view blade laravel like this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ITEM NUMBER</th>
        <th>TOTAL QUANTITY</th>
        <th>LOCATION-A</th>
        <th>LOCATION-B</th>
    </tr>
        @foreach($items as $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $item->item_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->total_quantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item['location-a'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item['location-b'] }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
</table>
```

It works. But my key of the array is dynamic. The key can change

So the array can change like this :

```
#attributes: array:5 [▼
  "item_number" => "AB-0001"
  "total_quantity" => "500"
  "location-a" => "500"
]
```

Or can change like this :

```
#attributes: array:5 [▼
  "item_number" => "AB-0001"
  "total_quantity" => "1500"
  "location-a" => "500"
  "location-b" => "500"
  "location-c" => "500"
]
```

So the location is dynamic

How do I set it in the laravel view blade so that it can adjust to dynamic arrays?

**Update**

If I `echo '<pre>';print_r($data);'</pre>';die();`, the result like this :

```
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator Object
(
    [total:protected] => 2428
    [lastPage:protected] => 1214
    [items:protected] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
        (
            [items:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => App\Models\ItemDetail Object
                        (
                            [table:protected] => items_details
                            [fillable:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => item_number
                                    [1] => quantity
                                    ...
                                )

                            [connection:protected] => mysql
                            [primaryKey:protected] => id
                            [keyType:protected] => int
                            [incrementing] => 1
                            [with:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [withCount:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [perPage:protected] => 15
                            [exists] => 1
                            [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                            [attributes:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [item_number] => AB-0001
                                    [total_quantity] => 1000
                                    [location-a] => 500
                                    [location-b] => 500
                                )

                            [original:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [item_number] => AB-0001
                                    [total_quantity] => 1000
                                    [location-a] => 500
                                    [location-b] => 500
                                )

                            [changes:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [casts:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [dates:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [dateFormat:protected] => 
                            [appends:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [observables:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [relations:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [touches:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [timestamps] => 1
                            [hidden:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [visible:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [guarded:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => *
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => App\Models\ItemDetail Object
                        (
                            [table:protected] => items_details
                            [fillable:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => item_number
                                    [1] => quantity
                                    ...
                                )

                            [connection:protected] => mysql
                            [primaryKey:protected] => id
                            [keyType:protected] => int
                            [incrementing] => 1
                            [with:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [withCount:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [perPage:protected] => 15
                            [exists] => 1
                            [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                            [attributes:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [item_number] => AB-0002
                                    [total_quantity] => 1500
                                    [location-a] => 1000
                                    [location-b] => 500
                                )

                            [original:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [item_number] => AB-0002
                                    [total_quantity] => 1500
                                    [location-a] => 1000
                                    [location-b] => 500
                                )


                            [changes:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [casts:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [dates:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [dateFormat:protected] => 
                            [appends:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [observables:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [relations:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [touches:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [timestamps] => 1
                            [hidden:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [visible:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [guarded:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => *
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [perPage:protected] => 2
    [currentPage:protected] => 1
    [path:protected] => http://my-project.test/admin/item-detail
    [query:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fragment:protected] => 
    [pageName:protected] => page
)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to sort the arrays?

Comment: @Classified No. You try to read my question again

Comment: Can you show controller method where you get this collection?

Comment: @yrv16 I update my question

Comment: You need has array structure like `[['item_number' => ['name' ='th mane', 'value_1' => 'value_1'],...],...]` and it'll help you to solve your task.

Comment: @yrv16 I'm still confused your mean. Please answer this question with a detail answer

Comment: I can answer for first your question without update which you added later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```
@php
$counts = array_map('count', $data);
$key = array_flip($counts)[max($counts)];
@endphp
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach ($data[$key] as $key => $value)
            <th>{{$key}}</th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
        @foreach($data as $value)
        <tr>
            @foreach ($value as $key => $value)
                <td>{{$value}}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: I want header of table also dynamic. So in the tag `<th>`, it also dynamic. Your script is not dynamic

Comment: Ok let me check it out

Comment: @SuccessMan code for dynamic header added. You can write PHP code in the controller and pass $key to view also.

Comment: There exist error like this : `array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array`

Comment: See my update question. `$data` array in the form of pagination and that is collection

Comment: vardump your $data and check if is it array or not

Comment: you have an "items" array in "items" collection, is it what you have to print, then replace $data with it. Like $data->items->items *not tested

Comment: Yes. Actually $data array is items array. I just replace it

Comment: Are you getting data you wanted in it? B'coz It just shows table name, primary key etc..

Comment: Yes. See in the `attributes` section. The data array there. The example like this : `#attributes: array:5 [▼
  "item_number" => "AB-0001"
  "total_quantity" => "100"
  "location-a" => "500"
  "location-b" => "500"
]`

Comment: Then just pass attributes in inner foreach

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If I debug `$data` in the controller laravel(In laravel is `dd($data)`), the result like image on the my question

Comment: I update my question again. Hopefully you can understand

Comment: print_r $data array

Comment: Oh man solution for you problem is already here. Will please print your collection so that i can help u to implement it.  U just have to itrate attributes in innerloop.

Comment: Look at my question.  I had update it.  The image is my collectiom

Comment: This is dd output .. use print_r instead

Comment: Now it works. I convert collection to array before display in the table. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

your question is quite confusing, if key is dynamic, you can also send an array with of "key" and can send an array with keys like this

```
//In your controller
$values = array(
    array('item_number' => 'AB-0001','total_quantity' => '500', 'location-a' => '500'),
    array('item_number' => 'AB-0002','total_quantity' => '5000', 'location-a' => '5000'),
    array('item_number' => 'AB-0003','total_quantity' => '2000', 'location-a' => '2000'),
);

$data = 
[
    'keys' => ['item_number', 'total_quantity', 'location_a'],
    'values' => $values
];

return view('some_blade', $data);
```

In your blade you can access like this

```
    @foreach($values as $value) 
     <tr>
       @foreach($keys as $k)
            <td>{{ $value[$k]; }}</td>
       @endforeach
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

hope that helps.